# Override dependencies properties by parameters value in TeamCity 9

Tags: dependencies, teamcity

In TeamCity 9 I have two build configurations: A, B which depends on A (snapshot dependency). Sometimes A starts alone, sometimes in chain with B.
I want to change `build.number` of A to (for example) `0.<build.counter of B>` when A triggered by B.

According to [docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-OverridingDependenciesProperties):

> Since TeamCity 9.0, there is a possibility to override the
>   dependencies parameters by redefining them in the dependent build. For
>   example, build configuration A depends on B and B depends on C; A has
>   the ability to change parameters in any of its dependencies using the
>   following format:
>
> `reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>`

Ok, I created configuration parameter in B: `reverse.dep.A.build.number`=`0.%build.counter%`.
So, when I start the build chain I suppose *build.number* of A will changed to `0.123` (for example, *build.counter* of B equal to 123), but instead the **string** `0.%build.counter%` has been passed to A and A uses own property `build.counter`.

How to pass exactly values of TeamCity parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consider question**
There is no way to pass value to dependency build with `reverse.dep.` syntax.

> reverse.dep parameters values are passed down the dependency chain as is.

(from here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40772)

---

**Consider problem**

1. Create configuration "C"
2. Add to "C" snapshot dependency from "A" **with** "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" option
3. Add to "C" snapshot dependency from "B" **without** same option.
4. Pass parameter from "B" to "A" through `reverse.dep.A.use_C_number`=`true`, so "A" knows what counter to use.
5. Use this parameter in script (new build step) in "A", for example (PowerShell):

   ```
   # Gets build.number of "C"
   $C_num = "%dep.C.build.number%"

   # Gets 'use_C_number' parameter
   $use_C_number = "%use_C_number%"

   # Change current build.number if needed
   if ($use_C_number -eq "true") {
     Host-Write "##teamcity[buildNumber '1.2.3.$C_num']"
   }
   ```

In this case "C" will be triggered only by "B" and not by "A", because "A" will always use "suitable" build of "C" ("C" has no VCS root attached).
**Note**: it should be at least one finished build of "C".
**Note**: I'm not sure about "suitable" build in all cases, because [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Snapshot+Dependencies#SnapshotDependencies-SuitableBuilds) is not clear for situation with no VCS root attached to build configuration, but it works. In any case there is a [question](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40865) in TeamCity tracker.

So, C's build.counter will be incremented only when "B" is queued.
When "A" started alone it use default `build.number`.

P.S. Thanks to Nikita Skvortsov for targetting me to the solution.

Comment: Glad you have your problem fixed.

Answer (score 4):

By the time "A" build starts, the "B" build is still in queue and so there is no build number available. The %build.number% parameter could not be resolved and was passed literally.

Try creating the "C" configuration and add a snapshot dependency on it (from both A and B). Set build number format in both A and B to `%dep.C.system.build.number%`
This way you will have A and B share same counter.

Comment: This way I always will have `build.number` of C configuration in A. And it will incremented each time A starts. But I need counter incrementation only when A triggered by B configuration (not by human).