# How/Where to set reverse dependency parameter (reverse.dep) in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a TeamCity build configuration A and B, where B is dependent on A. I need to pass a parameter from B to A when B is triggered.

This is related to question: [Override dependencies properties by parameters value in TeamCity 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795326/override-dependencies-properties-by-parameters-value-in-teamcity-9)

and the teamcity documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-OverridingDependenciesProperties)

I need to find WHERE/HOW to use this reverse.dep to set the parameter in the dependent build? In the Project Configuration Parameters section, I can add Configuration/Environment/build parameters, but they take a Name/Value pair. So, pardon my ignorance here, but am not able to make out where to specify this reverse logic.

Thanks

Comment: So A depends on something passing a parameter to it? It seems these two are mutually dependent on each other, why not have 1 build configuration that builds them both?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: A can be build independently also, where that parameter is a Prompt parameter entered by the user. When Running B though, it then needs to pass/set this parameter in A

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it!

We just need to add a new Configuration Parameter in B with name as `reverse.dep.<btId>.paramName` and its value as the intended value that needs to be passed.

Imp: As noted in the TeamCity documentation -

> As the parameter's values should be known at that stage, they can only
>   be defined either as build configuration parameters or in the custom
>   build dialog.

Comment: you say <btId> - is that the build task ID from "A" which B depends upon?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this argument `reverse.dep.*.<parameterName>` into your build configuration to be consumed by the dependent builds.

for instance, if A depends on B, so if you trigger B and you want to use parameter defined in B into A, then simply add new parameter with name `"reverse.dep.*.<parameterName>" Value: <Value>`  in Configuration Parameters of B and then you can use this parameter with %parameterName% into A build CLI or anywhere.